# plot split character vector in consistent location

Tags: r

Alright I decided to waste the evening making a hangman game in R.  Got everything looking pretty good except an unknown number of letters that get plotted as seen here:

```
a
b
f
d
g
```

Here's an example/attempt using `text` and `mtext`:

```
FUN <- function(n) {
    plot.new()   
    mtext("wrong", side = 3, cex=1.5, adj = 0, padj = 1, col = "red") 
    wrong <- letters[1:n]
    text(0, .8, paste(wrong, collapse = "\n"), offset=.3, cex=1.5)
}

FUN(5)
FUN(10)

FUN2 <- function(n) {
    plot.new()   
    mtext("wrong", side = 3, cex=1.5, adj = 0, padj = 1, col = "red") 
    wrong <- letters[1:n]
    mtext(paste(wrong, collapse = "\n"), side = 3, cex=1.5,
        adj = 0, padj = 2.5)
}

FUN2(5)
FUN2(10)
```

How can I make it so the `a` in both `FUN(5)` and `FUN(10)` plots in the same location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - way to go! R Games! You should totally make a package out of it so I can play ;)

For `text` you can use the `adj` argument, if you set it to 1. Then the `(x,y)` coordinates provided to `text` refer to the top-left corner of the rectangle that contains the text.

> adj: one or two values in [0, 1] which specify the x (and
>             optionally y) adjustment of the labels.  On most devices
>             values outside that interval will also work.

```
FUN <- function(n) {
    plot.new()   
    mtext("better?", side = 3, cex=1.5, adj = 0, padj = 1, col = "red") 
    wrong <- letters[1:n]
    text(0, .8, paste(wrong, collapse = "\n"), offset=.3, cex=1.5, adj=c(0,1))
}
```

Note `adj=c(0,1)`, 0 being x alignment and 1 being y alignment (the documentation doesn't really make this clear but since it's a value in `[0,1]` I assume it to be an adjustment of position as a fraction of the label length in that dimension).

Similarly for `mtext` you need to use `padj=1`, being top alignment according to the documentation (since your text direction is left to right). The `adj` argument is the left-right alignment.

```
FUN2 <- function(n) {
    plot.new()   
    mtext("better?", side = 3, cex=1.5, adj = 0, padj = 1, col = "red") 
    wrong <- letters[1:n]
    mtext(paste(wrong, collapse = "\n"), side = 3, cex=1.5,
        adj = 0, padj = 1) # adj=1 means text on right side instead of left.
}
```

(Are you going to do humorous stick man figures?? This sounds so fun :D)

Comment: Thank you much.  Here's the package: `library(devtools); install_github("hangman", "trinker")`

Comment: Though I tried it in Rstudio and if the window isn't the right size it becomes unstable.